# Create soft links of files that are inside subfolders that contain spaces?

Tags: linux, file-management

I have a folder that has several folders with ISOs in each. Some names of the files and folders have spaces.
Here is an example folder structure:

```
/ISOs
-CentOS
--Centos6
---Centos6_x64.iso
---Centos6_x86.iso
-Windows_10_Pro
--Windows_10_Pro.iso
-Windows 10 Enterprise
--Windows 10 Enterprise.iso
```

Commands tried:

```
find /mnt/fs1/Shares/Software$/ISOs/ -name \*.iso | xargs ln -sf /mnt/fs2/Shares/Images$/proxmox/template/iso
```

and

```
for file in "$(find /mnt/fs1/Shares/Software$/ISOs/ -name \*.iso)"; do ln -sf /mnt/fs2/Shares/Images$/server/template/iso/$file;
```

With the use of the above commands, it will create links to the files, but leaves out anything that has a space in either the name of the folder/sub folder or the name of the file:

```
/iso
-Centos6_x64.iso
-Centos6_x86.iso
-Windows_10_Pro.iso
```

What is the best way for me to list out all files contained in this folder?

Comment: The first command is wrong, but the second will work if you escape the dollar signs `\$`, apart from `$sign`, which should be enclosed in double-quotes `"$sign"`.

Answer (score 0):

When there are spaces in strings the shell is interpreting these as separate commands.  You need to encapsulate the path in quotes so the shell knows its a single unit.

```
for file in "$(find /mnt/fs1/Shares/Software$/ISOs/ -name \*.iso)"; do ln -sf "/mnt/fs2/Shares/Images$/server/template/iso/$file;"
```

I tried a similar command on my system, and an easier way to do this would be

```
find /mnt/fs1/Shares/Software$/ISOs/ -name "*.iso" -exec ln -sf {} \;
```

Comment: Because of quoting, `for file in "$(find …)"; …` will almost work only if `find` prints exactly one path. Without double-quoting it becomes the [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). So it's flawed either way. "Almost work", because `/mnt/fs2/Shares/Images$/server/template/iso/$file;` makes no sense and there is no `done` in the syntax. The rest of the answer seems right (I would add `cd /where/to/place/links` before `find` though) and I'm willing to upvote it, but only after the flawed command is explicitly discredited.